# Why is revising bad?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, revisions-list

[image]

For some reason, the revision text is in red (a colour I see as negative). Is there any reason for this - to me it makes it seem like revising / editing is bad, asking / commenting and getting badges is meh, and answering is good:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not red -- really more of a maroon.

Comment: @Josh it seems negative to me... @Downvoter Any reason for the DV?`

Comment: @Tim perhaps they disagree that this is worth discussing, or that it looks like a negative thing, or that...

Comment: I would personally love to see them redo the color scheme for the activity history to match the [awesome colors from the moderator's timeline](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3x6jU.png) (note that an edit would be considered a "history" event). Those colors work very well and make it extremely easy to see the different types of actions that occur on a post. I'll also note that red is reserved for flags in that timeline. I'm not sure if blue is used, maybe they could use it for badges (since those wouldn't appear in a post's timeline (though that would be interesting to see in the timeline))?

Comment: Red is a power colour, so a revision is a power move